# Serverless with aws container images

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless, serverless-framework, amazon-ecr

i am trying to use aws ecr for my serverless application but i am failing to do so,
my main problem is the 50mb upload limit lambda has, and this is the config in my serverless (i am not sure if it is correct since there is not lots of documentation about it online)
(i am using aws-nodejs-typescript template)

addFriend is the function that i am trying to build with docker.

[image]

this is my Dockerfile

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/nodejs:14 as builder
WORKDIR /usr/app
COPY package.json handler.ts  ./
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build


FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/nodejs:14
WORKDIR ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}
COPY --from=builder /usr/app/dist/* ./
CMD ["handler.main"]
```

and my `serverless.ts`

```
  const serverlessConfiguration: AWS = {
    ...
    custom: {
      esbuild: {
        bundle: true,
        minify: false,
        sourcemap: true,
        exclude: ['aws-sdk'],
        target: 'node14',
        define: { 'require.resolve': undefined },
        platform: 'node',
      },
      ...
    },
    plugins: ['serverless-esbuild'],
    provider: {
      name: 'aws',
      runtime: 'nodejs14.x',
      profile: <PROFILE>,
      region: 'us-east-1',
      stage: 'dev',
      apiGateway: {
        minimumCompressionSize: 1024,
        shouldStartNameWithService: true,
      },
      iamRoleStatements: [
        {
          Effect: 'Allow',
          Action: ['s3:*', 'sns:*'],
          Resource: '*',
        },
      ],
      ecr: {
        images: {
          addfriendfunction: {
            path: './src/functions/addFriend',
          },
        },
      },
      lambdaHashingVersion: '20201221',
    },
    functions: {
      ...
      addPushToken,
      addFriend: {
        image: {
          name: 'addfriendfunction',
        },
        events: [
          {
            http: {
              method: 'get',
              path: 'api/v1/add-friend',
            },
          },
        ],
      },
```

the error in the console is:

> TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type
> string. Received undefined

i am stuck with this issue unable to continue working, is there any solution for this with serverless framework?

Answer (score 0):

Follow this [guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html) for nodejs.
Can you try copy js code. For example something like: `.esbuild/.build/src/functions/addFriend/handler.js` instead of this step:
`COPY package.json handler.ts  ./`